# How to properly add inline Javascript code to a webform with javascript injector module

Tags: 7, javascript, rules, webforms

I have recently started leaning Drupal 7. I have built my first Webform and I'd like to add a field that calculates automatically number of days between two dates as shown in below [image: the picture] I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://1013.fi/cms/interactive-drupal-web-forms-jquery-javascript-library) but I didn't understand it so I tried to use the module js injector to solve the problem!

This is the JS injection rule that I used

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$( "#edit-submitted-startdate,#edit-submitted-enddate" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
})

$( "#edit-submitted-startdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
$( "#edit-submitted-enddate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

$('#edit-submitted-enddate').change(function() {
var start = $('#edit-submitted-startdate').datepicker('getDate');
var end   = $('#edit-submitted-enddate').datepicker('getDate');

if (start<end) {
var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
$('#edit-submitted-days').val(days);
}
else {
alert ("You cant come back before you have been!");
$('#edit-submitted-startdate').val("");
$('#edit-submitted-enddate').val("");
$('#edit-submitted-days').val("");
}
}); 
}); 
});
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me finding the error? It seems I didn't write it well on Drupal as js rule.

This is the javascript code that I want to write:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"             href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#startdate,#enddate" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
})

$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
$( "#enddate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

$('#enddate').change(function() {
var start = $('#startdate').datepicker('getDate');
var end   = $('#enddate').datepicker('getDate');

if (start<end) {
var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
$('#days').val(days);
}
else {
alert ("You cant come back before you have been!");
$('#startdate').val("");
$('#enddate').val("");
$('#days').val("");
}
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Any error message displayed in console?

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use proper Drupal jQuery Syntax.

Screw the js injector module, you can do the same like this:

Create a block, for Text format select Full HTML and put this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

(function ($) {
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( "#edit-submitted-startdate,#edit-submitted-enddate" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
})

$( "#edit-submitted-startdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
$( "#edit-submitted-enddate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

$('#edit-submitted-enddate').change(function() {
var start = $('#edit-submitted-startdate').datepicker('getDate');
var end   = $('#edit-submitted-enddate').datepicker('getDate');

if (start<end) {
var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
$('#edit-submitted-days').val(days);
}
else {
alert ("You cant come back before you have been!");
$('#edit-submitted-startdate').val("");
$('#edit-submitted-enddate').val("");
$('#edit-submitted-days').val("");
}
}); 

});
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Place the block in some region.

[image]

For **Visibility Settings**

Pages, select `only listed pages` and type the url for your webform.

[image]

Comment: I flow all the steps but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: i disabled the module js  [link](http://prntscr.com/butkjt)
i create the block as you told me [link](http://prntscr.com/butlkk)
[link](http://prntscr.com/butm4r)
[link](http://prntscr.com/butmct)
[link](http://prntscr.com/butmks)

Comment: @SuperMario on this [link](http://prntscr.com/butlkk) you need to use **FULL HTML** as your text formatter not Filter HTML.

Comment: it still doesn't work :/ [link](http://prntscr.com/bv68ti)

Comment: @SuperMario did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes i clear the cache

Comment: @SuperMario I see the problem, you need to make visibility settings like in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank youuuuu so much finally it's works [link](http://prntscr.com/bv6o2p)

Comment: @SuperMario you're welcome `:)`

Answer (score -1):

There are two basic ways to do it in Drupal: 
[Drupal - Community Documentation - Adding JavaScript to a Webform](https://www.drupal.org/node/342183)

Comment: Please update your answer with the relevant bits from the link you provided in order to help future proof your answer.